# Cheapest object values from two object arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Ok so this might seem simple, but somehow I am not getting the desired result here. I have two objects like this:

Comment: you recomend using reduces? or backtracking?

Comment: Array prototype has some pretty powerful methods, but for this you would only need 
`sort()` and `find()`. I'm not going to write a full answer because that would prevent you from learning yourself (and is not the purpose of SO)  :D

Comment: @funkizer I think you misunderstood the question. It's not possible solely with `find()`.

Comment: Yeah, added `sort` there.

Comment: Sort outbound and inbound routes by price. Then find an outbound route that gives you the lowest total price when added to a matching inbound route. Depending on personal preference, you can also use `reduce` to do that instead of mutating some variable outside the `find` loop (I would use reduce).

Comment: You can also combine `sort`,  `map`, and `find`, if you want to first get an array of all inbound-outbound routes (cheapest options of each), and then find the cheapest of them all.

Answer (score 0):

#### For the simple case of one pair of journeys, you don't need backtracking

To avoid doing the whole task for you, and spoiling the learning experience, I have provided a structure which will produce an output. All you need to do is fill in the correct conditions required to make a pair of legs into a valid round trip.

#### How it works

In a limited-size task like this, you can enumerate all the possibilities and pick the one with the smallest total price.

This is achieved here by two nested .forEach loops.

Meanwhile, you keep a track of the "lowest total price so far", and the pair of legs that achieved that price. Start off with an empty object for that. At the innermost point of the loop, you compare the price that you are testing, against the lowest so far. If it beats the lowest price so far (or there is not yet any lowest price, because it is the first time round the loop), store it as the new lowest so far.

Best of luck in your assignment!

```js
const legs = {
  "outbound": [{
      "id": 1,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "NAPOLI",
      "arrivalCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "ticketPrice": 15
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "ferryCompany": "MSC",
      "departureCity": "NAPOLI",
      "arrivalCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "ticketPrice": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "ferryCompany": "MSC",
      "departureCity": "HAMBURG",
      "arrivalCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "ticketPrice": 25
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "NAPOLI",
      "arrivalCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "ticketPrice": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "NAPOLI",
      "arrivalCity": "MARSELLA",
      "ticketPrice": 30
    }
  ],
  "inbound": [{
      "id": 11,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "arrivalCity": "NAPOLI",
      "ticketPrice": 50
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "ferryCompany": "MSC",
      "departureCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "arrivalCity": "NAPOLI",
      "ticketPrice": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "arrivalCity": "HAMBURG",
      "ticketPrice": 25
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "ferryCompany": "MSC",
      "departureCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "arrivalCity": "HAMBURG",
      "ticketPrice": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "ferryCompany": "Grimaldi",
      "departureCity": "ROTTERDAM",
      "arrivalCity": "NAPOLI",
      "ticketPrice": 30
    }
  ]
}

const lowest = {}

legs.outbound.forEach(outboundLeg => {
  legs.inbound.forEach(inboundLeg => {
    if (outboundLeg.departureCity === inboundLeg.arrivalCity
      // Add more conditions here
    ) {
      price = outboundLeg.ticketPrice + inboundLeg.ticketPrice
      if (!lowest.price || price < lowest.price) {
        lowest.price = price;
        lowest.outboundLeg = outboundLeg
        lowest.inboundLeg = inboundLeg
      }
    }

  })
})

console.log(lowest)
```

#### Of course you will have to add the full set of validity criteria, in the middle.

I have only put in one, to get you started.

#### This won't work if the total number of possibilities to test is large

For example, with 10 stages of journey, with 10 options at each stage, you would be testing 10**10 possible paths in principle, which would be disastrously time-consuming.

So instead you would probably change the leg information into a dictionary whose key is "where I am starting from", with an array of options of journey that start at that point. That way, you can quickly get a list of which nodes you can go to, from any given node.

Then you could enumerate all possibilities, if the number of possibilities *from* each intermediate point was not too large.

#### If the number of options from each location is large, you couldn't even do this

For example, if there were 10 legs to the journey, and (say) 10 possible outbound options from each city, that is still 10**10 combinations which would be impossible.

In that case you might want to keep a dictionary of:

```
{ 
   "place I can get to at some stage": { 
    // info about cheapest way to get there
    "path": [leg1, leg2, leg3 etc.], 
    "totalPrice": 55
   },

   "another place I can get to at some stage: { 
   ... },
   ...
 }
```

#### If that is infeasible, because the number of locations is too large, or all the info is not available up-front, or expensive to ask for

Then you might want to consider an algorithm that only follows one path at a time, and it will need to be able to backtrack.